# Why does NodeJS treat a number as an integer?

Tags: node.js, numbers, bigint

I am subtracting two very big numbers from each other. I then try to divide the result by 1000.0, to convert from millisec to seconds. For reasons beyond me, I am losing the decimals. Can someone explain me why?

```
let intervalMs = (interval.toMs - interval.fromMs) // Two big numbers
console.log(intervalMs) // Prints "43200000"
let intervalSec = intervalMs / 1000.0
console.log(intervalSec) // Prints "43200" ?!?!
```

I also tried "casting" the intervalMs to a number:

```
let intervalMs = Number(interval.toMs - interval.fromMs)
```

But the results are the same

Comment: JavaScript only has one kind of number. Why would `43200000 / 1000` need more significant figures?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Not relevant to this question, but these days, JavaScript also has `BigInt` and in a couple of years (probably) will have [some kind of "decimal" type](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decimal). :-)

Comment: *"I also tried "casting" the intervalMs to a number:"* That's not a cast, it's a *conversion* (JavaScript doesn't have casts [I think that's true for loosely-typed languages in general]). But it doesn't do anything in this case, the input value is *already* a number, so passing it through the `Number` function returns it unchanged. `1000`, `1000.0`, and `1000.00` are all exactly the same number value, just written with differing numbers of zeros after the decimal point.

Comment: what is the answer you're expecting?

Comment: I was fooled. It's not an integer. It's just printed as one... My bad. Thanks for your input guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's becase decimals equal 0, try to divide by 3003 you will get decimals.

To get 0 decimals use:

```
console.log(intervalSec.toFixed(10));
```